# in the flutter i tried calling : _addfromInteger

Tags: flutter, dart

```
void _resetQuiz() {
        setState(() {
          _questionIndex = 0;
          _totalScore = 0;
        });
      }

      void answerQuestion(score) {
        _totalScore += score;
        setState(() {

          _questionIndex += 1;
        });
        print(_questionIndex);
        print(_totalScore);
        print("Answer chosen !%n");
      }
```

Here my code below. I want to know the principale cause.

This is the code

[image: this is the code]

Comment: You're not pasting the relevant code. Where did you call `_addfromInteger`?

Comment: i am a beginner and i am trying to build Quiz app ; so i didn' t call' _addfromInteger' , i just had increment the value score, and this error comes!

Comment: but the error came from `_addfromInteger`. Where did you use `_addfromInteger`?

Answer (score 0):

this problem occurs due to using a non intialized variable => null:
`class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {`
 `int _questionIndex = 0;`
`int _totalScore = 0;`
 `int _score ;` **<---------- score = null**